# How would I go about aligning my input boxes in the center of a div?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, alignment

I'd like to align all input elements within my form to the center of my div which is in my content page using grid. Also I'd like it to dynamically adjust if I were to increase or decrease the window size in order to flow with grid work method.

Below is the code snippet.

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
}

.form {
  margin: 0 0 100px 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 320px;
}

.text-box {
  width: 450px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="./getting-started.html">Getting Started</a>
      <a href="./tracks.html">Tracks</a>
      <a href="./contact-us.html">Contact Us</a>
    </header>
    <main>
      <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="form">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required><br>
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required><br>
          <label for="occ">Occupation:</label>
          <input type="text" id="occ" placeholder="Occupation"><br>
          <label for="xp">Experience:</label>
          <input type="text" id="xp" placeholder="Years/Months"><br>
          <label for="rs">Rolling Chassis:</label>
          <input type="text" id="rs" placeholder="Model"><br>
          <label for="engine">Engine:</label>
          <input type="text" id="engine" placeholder="Manufacturer"><br>
        </div>
        <input class="text-box" type="text" name="name" equired><br>
      </form>
    </main>
    <advert>
      <img src="./banner-ads.jpg" alt="A banner about banner adds">
    </advert>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer>Maximilian Crosby ©</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flex layout to easily align items in the middle

```
.form {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: thanks! What if I'd like my text to be to the left of the input? also how would I go about making the input boxes bigger so that the user can type more? Like a paragraphs worth of content.

Comment: @Maximilian you can wrap each input/label in a div

Comment: If I do that the text and the boxes are centralised again and looks messy I'd like the input boxes to be in line regardless of what text is to the left of them.

Comment: You can give the input 50% width and the label 50% width and align the text the way you want using text-align for the label

Answer (score 0):

To center your form, you can add the code below to `form` (not the class .form) About the responsive, you can do something similar to `bootstrap` or use bootstrap or use `@media` to set the width of the class `.form` to whatever size you want depends on screen size.

```
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```